# Character at break stripped

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

We have this VB.NET method.

Purpose: A string with multiple lines of characters must fit in to a column on a printed report.  The string needs to pre-processed to have line breaks before or at given number of characters, the line break can't be part way though a word or a number.  Can't strip any characters, other than spaces.
Further details:
 - "," must be at end of line, not put at beginning of new line

I can't figure out how to resolve: the character at the line break is stripped, and it should not be unless it is a space.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function SplitOn(ByVal initial As String, ByVal MaxCharacters As Integer) As List(Of String)
        Dim lines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(initial) = False Then
            Dim targetGroup As String = "Line"
            Dim pattern As String = String.Format("(?<{0}>.{{1,{1}}})(?:\W|$)", targetGroup, MaxCharacters)
            lines = Regex.Matches(initial, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).OfType(Of Match)().[Select](Function(mt) mt.Groups(targetGroup).Value).ToList()
        End If
        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
            lines(i) = lines(i).TrimEnd(New Char() {CChar(vbCr), CChar(vbLf)})
        Next

        Return lines
    End Function
```

**Test Cases**

initial =
"RW/40mm,6/50mm,4,2
N=6"

Case 1:
MaxCharacters  = 10

Current Result:
RW/40mm,6
50mm,4,2
N=6

Required Result:
RW/40mm,6/
50mm,4,2
N=6

Problem: the / after 6 is stripped, it should be retained

Case 2
MaxCharacters  = 9

Current Result:
RW/40mm
6/50mm,4
2
N=6

Required Result:
RW/40mm,
6/50mm,4,
2
N=6

Problem: need to keep , after 40mm and after 4

Comment: What is the intent of the function? Can you [edit] the question show us the values of `pattern`, please?

Comment: Why do you expect those characters to be retained? Your pattern says find the longest string shorter than MaxCharacters ending in a non-word character which is thrown away, so "RW/40mm,6" is 9 characters (shorter than 10) and ends in "/" which is thrown away.

Comment: @AndrewMorton `pattern` is defined in the function.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what you are attempting to accomplish instead of how you aren't accomplishing it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've improved the question. @NetMage how do I stop the "/" being thrown away? which part of the code is doing that? (I'm very weak on regex)

Comment: @NetMage I thought it might help us, and the OP, to see example values of `pattern` rather than just its definition.

Comment: The `(?:\W|$)` at the end of the pattern throws away the character that matches the `\W`. Do you prefer the non-word character to end the line, or is it okay to begin the next line? If it is okay to begin the next line, replace that with `(?=\W|$)`.

Comment: To end the line instead, use `(?<=\W|$)`.

Answer (score 0):

@NetMage gave the answer, thanks.
"To end the line instead, use (?<=\W|$)"